# Warning mb_convert_encoding() Unknown encoding "WINDOWS-1256"

Tags: php, character-encoding, iconv

getting error while converting windows-1256 in mb_convert_encoding():

> Warning: mb_convert_encoding(): Unknown encoding "WINDOWS-1256"
>   (K:/xampp/htdocs/master/trunk/__swift/includes/functions.php:715)

I know there is one alternative function iconv() by which I can resolved this problem but I know there must be some problem with iconv() aswell. I am digging into both of these, why and where these both are being use. any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

There's no reason to believe that the error message is incorrect:

> Unknown encoding "WINDOWS-1256"

You mention two functions:

- Supported encodings for `mb_convert_encoding()` are listed in the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php). There's no mention to Win-1256. They can also be obtained with the [mb_list_encodings()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-list-encodings.php) function. It appears that you cannot use this extension with such encoding.
- Supported encodings for `iconv()` are listed in the [libiconv web site](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/). There we can find `CP1256`. Yes, it's exactly the same encoding, but `iconv()` does not support the other alias (which is BTW the official IANA name).

Comment: Well, “valid” as per what libiconv regards as valid, which is what matters when using that softwaee. It is protocol-ignorant, however, since the only defined name in the authoritative IANA [Character Sets](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml) registry is windows-1256.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - I've tweaked my answer to clarify that.

Comment: Error message is correct, your error warning must be disabled. you can also check : http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php 'windows-1256' is not listed their.

Comment: I totally misread the question. Your error message is clearly about MB functions. I've updated my answer to make it more useful.